# Hausdorff's formula proof

Tags: calculus, physics, mathematical-physics

How do we prove Hausdorff's formula in the following form by pulling the operator B in $e^A B$ to the left side in the following form ?

$e^ABe^{-A} = B + [A,B]+\frac{1}{2!}[A,[A,B]]+...$

I made some progress as far as to acquire the B factor on the right hand side of the equation but I am unable to get the rest. Any ideas ?

Comment: Why do you think of the clean Wikipedia proof as messy?

Answer (score 0):

**Claim:** $$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}\lambda} \left( e^{\lambda A} B e^{-\lambda A}\right) = e^{\lambda A} [A,B] e^{-\lambda A} $$

This claim is easily proven by differentiation. Denoting the function above by $f(\lambda)$, we note further that
$$f''(\lambda) = e^{\lambda A} [A,[A,B]] e^{-\lambda A}$$
and so on. We can write $f(\lambda)$ as a Taylor Series around $\lambda = 0$:
$$f(\lambda) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}\lambda^n$$
and the result follows by letting $\lambda = 1$.